# Magento 2 how to remove “SKU field” via Layout Update XML?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I'm stuck on this:

I need to remove the SKU field from product page only for few products, I'm sure that I can do it with "layout update XML" tab but all my attempts have failed.. any help? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution.

You have to mention the block container name also

> ```
> <referenceContainer name="product.info.stock.sku">
>        <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true" />
> </referenceContainer>
> ```

Here,`product.info.stock.sku` is the container name of your block.

> ```
> <referenceContainer name="{CONTAINER_NAME_OF_BLOCK}">
>        <referenceBlock name="{BLOCK_NAME_AT_LAYOUT}" remove="true" />
> </referenceContainer>
> ```

### If it not work then you can use the below solution also.

- Create a new container
- and  Move your block to this container
- After that remove container:

> ```
> <container name="my.new.sections" htmlTag="div" />
> <move element="product.info.sku" destination="my.new.sections" />
> <referenceContainer name="my.new.sections" remove="true" />
> ```

### Formula:

> ```
> <container name="{New_Conatiner_Name}" htmlTag="div" />
> <move element="{BLOCK_NAME_AT_LAYOUT}" destination="{New_Conatiner_Name}" />
> <referenceContainer name="{New_Conatiner_Name}" remove="true" />
> ```

Comment: No one works :(

I've tryed to add "<container name="my.new.sections" htmlTag="div" />
<move element="product.info.sku" destination="my.new.sections" />
<referenceContainer name="my.new.sections" remove="true" />" on layout update xml of an Item without success, I've tryed to add "<container name="my.new.sections" htmlTag="div" />" on catalog_product_view.xml and this code on layout update xml "<move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="my.new.sections" />
<referenceContainer name="my.new.sections" remove="true" />" but still the same, SKU is showing as usual

Comment: please ensure that your block name in layout is `product.info.sku`

Comment: Great, this one works:

<referenceContainer name="product.info.stock.sku">
       <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>

Needs only a cach:clean after save! :P THANK YOU!

Comment: Silly mistake was there:)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to backend
2. Select products that You need
3. Edit attributes and choose layout update.
4. Paste this:

> `<referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true" />`

and save

Update:
Add reference container around referenceBlock

> `<referenceContainer name="your container` ">

Ref:

https://inchoo.net/magento-2/bypassing-magento-2-layout-update-restrictions-admin/

Comment: I have already tried with this, but the result is an error on saving:

Element 'referenceBlock': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move, head, body ). Line: 1

Comment: Hmm This worked for all in product view xml.Maybe You could move this element only for this few products and hide it via css using specific classes.

Comment: I update my answer.

Comment: Still not working :(

I've added this to my custom layout update xml:


<referenceContainer name="content">
<container name="product.info.main">
<referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true" />
</container>
</referenceContainer>